# Privilege usage checks

Tags: android, privileged-account

What does it mean that "the permission system does not include checks for transitive privilege usage" (quote from a paper on [Privilege Escalation Attacks on Android](http://www.ei.rub.de/media/trust/veroeffentlichungen/2010/11/13/DDSW2010_Privilege_Escalation_Attacks_on_Android.pdf)).

Android grants app privileges during installation, but (as above) there's no some kind of checks. What is it about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means just what it says: the Android permission system does not try to identify transitive requests to use privilege.  For instance, if app A asks app B to do something on its behalf, and in response app B asks the underlying OS to do something, then the OS permission checks only take into account that B is requesting, not that the request originated with A and is being performed on A's behalf.

To understand in more detail, I suggest that you read the following papers:

[Android Permissions Demystified](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~afelt/android_permissions.pdf). Adrienne Porter Felt, Erika Chin, Steve Hanna, Dawn Song, and David Wagner.  CCS 2011.

[Quire: Lightweight Provenance for Smartphone Operating Systems](http://www.usenix.org/events/sec11/tech/full_papers/Dietz7-26-11.pdf).  Michael Dietz, Shashi Shekhar, Yuliy Pisetsky, Anhei Shu, and Dan S. Wallach.  Usenix Security 2011.

[Permission Re-Delegation: Attacks and Defenses](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~afelt/felt_usenixsec2011.pdf).  Adrienne Porter Felt, Helen Wang, Alex Moshchuk, Steve Hanna, and Erika Chin.  Usenix Security 2011.

Wikipedia on [the confused deputy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_Deputy).

P.S. In the future, when quoting from someone, you might want to provide the source of the quotation.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation and links to the resources. [The source of my question.](http://www.ei.rub.de/media/trust/veroeffentlichungen/2010/11/13/DDSW2010_Privilege_Escalation_Attacks_on_Android.pdf)